# Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 't'

Tags: php, preg-match

Help me plese :

```
 function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname)
 {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
 }
```

I got :

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 't'
```

Also, i have try:

```
    $pattern = "~<$tagname>(.*?)<\/$tagname>~";
```

In this case, I have :

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 146 in
```

Sure, I have try variants

```
$pattern = "/<".$tagname.">(.*?)<\/".$tagname.">/";
```

Any ideas ? )

Answer (score 1):

You need to change places of parameters in your **getTextBetweenTags** call. 'abc' is the name of the tag, not the string to search into, right?

```
$html = "<html><body><abc>HELLO</abc></body></html>";

function getTextBetweenTags( $string, $tagname ) {
    preg_match( "/\<{$tagname}\>(.*)\<\/{$tagname}\>/", $string, $matches );
    return $matches[1];
}

var_dump( getTextBetweenTags( $html, 'abc' ) );
```

Comment: Thank's for advice, but in this case, my function 

`code`$content = getTextBetweenTags('abc', $page);

work incorrect and instead of content in tag "abc", i got first tag in document $page.

Comment: Edited my answer, sorry, I misread your question at first. You call $content = getTextBetweenTags('abc', $page); while $content = getTextBetweenTags($page, 'abc'); is what you need.

Comment: Valentin, thank you so much, but in this case I got 

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in `code`     echo $matches[1]; //tag name

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in `code` in line echo $matches[2]; //text

in old code 

    preg_match( "/\<(\w+)\>(.*)\<\/\w+\>/", $tagname, $matches );
    echo $matches[1]; //tag name
    echo $matches[2]; //text

In new code : 
it is 

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in `code` return $matches[1];
Also, show's me `code` NULL ( i think due to the var_dump)

Comment: Just use the implementation from my answer, I updated it to accept the name of the tag as a parameter. The old version didn't allow that.

Comment: In new code : it is Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in code return $matches[1]; Also, show's me code NULL ( i think due to the var_dump)